# On a characterization of continuous convex functions

Tags: convex-analysis

I'm trying to prove the following know result:

**Theorem**
Let $I = (a,b)$ be an interval, and let $\phi \colon I \to \mathbb{R} $ be a continuos function. Then, $\phi$ is convex in $I$ if and only if
$$(*) \quad \phi(x) \leq \dfrac{1}{2\delta}\int_{x-\delta}^{x+\delta}\phi(t)dt,$$
for all $a < x-\delta < x < x+\delta < b$.

It is "easy" to prove, via Jensen's inequality, that if $\phi$ is convex then it satisfies $(*)$. However, I'm stuck proving the converse.

I've read that it can be deduced from the following result:

**Lemma**
In the upper setting, $\phi$ is convex in $I$ if and only if for any given $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and any interval $J = [c,d] \subset I$ the function $\phi+\alpha x$ attains its maximum in any of the limit points of $J$, that is, $c$ or $d$.

Any advice on how to finish the proof?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/927824/42969

Comment: Both questions seem related. I'll give it a go! Thanks.

Comment: In case it helps anyone: the ideas given in the post that @MartinR suggested also help to prove the problem I posted (and, indeed, are based in the lemma I gave). Thank you, mate.