# Average Value of a Function in an interval

Tags: calculus

Prove that if a differentiable function attains it's average value in any interval in the mid point of the interval then it is linear

I came across the converse of this problem and proved it easily and wondered if this is true but struggling to get a headstart. So any help in proving/disproving will be appreciated

Comment: This should answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/927824/42969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a differentiable function $f$ on an arbitrary interval $[a,b]$ with the assumption that it takes the average value at the midpoint.

\begin{align}
(b-a)f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) & = \int_a^b f(x) \ dx \\
\frac{b-a}{2}f'\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) + f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) &= f(b) \\
-a f'(a) + f(a) & = f(0) = K,
\end{align}
where I have redefined $a \to 2a$. This differential equation has solution $f(x) = K + c_1 x$, which proves the claim.

Answer (score 5):

Not true. consider $f(x)=x^3$ on the interval $[-1,1].$

Comment: Sorry I have edited the question now .I forgot to add differentiable factor

Comment: $x^3$ is differentiable...

Comment: is it true for any interval though (sorry for constantly changing the question).I just want to find a sufficient condition for the linearity condition to hold

Comment: @AmitKumarBasistha The answer by Gregory proves what you want. I assume you know that since you accepted his answer.

Answer (score 1):

As written, the statement is false.  For example, the discontinuous function
$$f(x) = -1,-1 \leq x \leq0,\\
f(x) = 0, x = 0\\
f(x) = 1,0<x \leq 1,$$
attains its average value at its midpoint, but is not linear.

Comment: sorry i should add the continuity factor.I shall edit my question

Comment: It is still false.  The other answers use $x^3$, which is continuous.

Comment: Am I wrong $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}x^3dx=\frac{b^4-a^4}{4}$ which isn't $\frac{a+b}{2}$

Comment: The answers provided use an interval symmetric about zero, for which a=−b.

Comment: Sorry I meant to use any interval in the question (Now I understand the value of using correct English).Really sorry for constantly changing the question

Answer (score 1):

A counter example: any odd function $f$ (like $x^3$) over a symmetric interval (like $[-1,1]$). Then $f(0)=0=\text{mean}$, but $f$ is not necessary linear

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the diffentiable condition